# Name of theorem about attracting fixed point

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f:\mathbb C\to \mathbb C$ be a complex entire function. I am trying to find the following result in the literature, but cannot remember its name.

> If $z_0$ is a fixed point of $f$, and $|f'(z_0)|<1$, then for every
> point $z$ near $z_0$, the sequence $z,f(z),f(f(z)),...$ converges.

How can I find this in a book?

Comment: Although I am not sure if it has a name, I can see that this is an immediate consequence of [Contraction Mapping Theorem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach_fixed-point_theorem).

Comment: This is just the most basic version of Lyapunov stability theory.